# Update Query with Order by while preventing two users updating the same row

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a SQL Server table with an `expirydate` column, I want to update rows on this table with the nearest `expirydate`, running two queries (select then update) won't work because two users may update the same row at the same time, so it has be one query.

The following query:

```
Update Top(5) table1 
Set col1 = 1 
Output deleted.* Into table2
```

This query runs fine but it doesn't sort by `expirydate`

This query:

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5 *
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY expirydate
) 
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = 1 
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO table2 
WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM q)
```

It works but again I run the risk of two users updating the same row at the same time

What options do I have to make this work?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you think 2 users will update the same row at the same time? An `UPDATE `will lock the rows, so unless you're implementing bad lock hints, it'll be impossible for 2 users to `UPDATE` 2 rows at the same time.

Comment: I meant two users will select the same records and therefore will update them consecutively

Comment: There is nothing to prevent a hundred queries one after another *even not at the same time* from changing the same rows, because you have no filter against earlier updates anyway (like `and col1 <> 1`) which, if you had, would also prevent the update anomaly you describe

Comment: *"I meant two users will select the same records"* Well if they are the "top 5" for both users, why is that a problem? That's what the above code wants to do. `UPDATE` the oldest 5 rows each time and change the value of `Col1` to `1` (even if it's already `1`). Seems like you aren't telling us what you *really* want to do here.

Comment: The query returns the rows data to the user so I don't want the same data to return to two users

Comment: Then you need to add a `WHERE` to not do so. `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table ORDER BY expirydate;` is always going to return the same rows if `expirydate` has unique values (and if the value of `expirydate` isn't changed)... This has nothing to do with the `UPDATE`. If that `SELECT` didn't return consistent results I would be *more* concerned.

Answer (score 0):

In these types of scenarios if you want a more *optimistic concurrency* approach, you need to include either an `Order By` AND / OR a `Where` clause to filter out the rows.

> In application design it is common to use `SELECT TOP (@count) FROM...` style queries to fill the interface, however to execute `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statements you would use the primary key to specifically identify the rows to modify.

As long as you are not executing delete, then you could use a timestamp or other date based descriminator column to ensure that your updates only affect the rows that haven't been changed since the last select.

So you could query the current time as part of the select query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as [Selected]
FROM table1
ORDER BY expirydate
```

or query for the timestamp first, and add a *created* column to the table to track new records so you do not include them in deletes, either way you need to ensure that the query to select the rows will always return the same records, even if I run it tomorrow, which means you will need to ensure that no one can modify the `expirydate` column, if that could be modified, then you can't use it as your primary *sort* **or** *filter* key.

```
DECLARE @selectedTimestamp DateTimeOffset = (SELECT SYSDatetimeoffset())
SELECT TOP 5 *, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as [Selected]
FROM table1
WHERE CREATED < @selectedTimestamp 
ORDER BY expirydate
```

Then in your update, make sure you only update the rows if they have not changed since the time that we selected them, this will either require you to have setup a standard audit trigger on the table to keep *created* and *modified* columns up to date, or for you to manage it manually in your update statement:

```sql
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5 *
    FROM table1
    WHERE CREATED < @selectedTimestamp
    ORDER BY expirydate
) 
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = 1, MODIFIED = SYSDatetimeoffset()
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO table2 
WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM q)
  AND MODIFIED < @selectedTimestamp
```

In this way we are effectively ignoring our change if another user has already updated records that were in the same or similar initial selection range.

Ultimately you could combine my initial advice to `UPDATE` based on the *primary key* **AND** the modified dates if you are genuinely concerned about the rows being updated twice.

If you need a more pessimistic approach, you could lock the rows with a specific user based flag so that other users cannot even select those rows, but that requires a much more detailed explanation.